# A way to ensure exclusive reads in MongoDb's findAndModify?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection (used as a job queue), from which multiple processes read records, using `findAndModify`. `FindAndModify` searches for records where the `active` field is "false", setting it to "true", so that other processes do not read the same record.

The problem is that looking at logs, I see that different processes still read the same records. This seems to occur when two processes read from the queue at the same time. Is there any way to make sure that one only process reads from a collection at a time?

I am using Mongo 2.2.3 and pymongo 2.2.

Many thanks!

EDIT: The logs in question are:

> worker.3     2013-03-18 23:57:45,434    default-worker-3
>   project_name    INFO    Queue job: job id: 5147a90f68e8fe0097002bdf
>
> worker.3     2013-03-18 23:57:47,608    default-worker-3
>   project_name    INFO    Input: 14497 docs
>
> worker.2     2013-03-18 23:57:45,440    default-worker-2
>   project_name    INFO    Queue job: job id: 5147a90f68e8fe0097002bdf
>
> worker.2     2013-03-18 23:57:47,658    default-worker-2
>   project_name    INFO    Input: 14497 docs

As you can see, worker.3 and worker.2 read the same job from the queue (it has the same mongodb id for both workers).

The find_and_modify command:

```
query = {"active": False}
try:
    return self.collection.find_and_modify(
            query=query,
            update={"$set": {"active": True}},
            upsert=False,
            sort={"added_on": 1},
            limit=1
        )
except Exception, exc:
    LOGGER.exception(exc)
```

Comment: Could you post the actual `findAndModify` call you are making?

Comment: result = self.collection.find_and_modify(
                                            query=query,
                                            update={"$set": {"active": True}},
                                            upsert=False,
                                            sort={"added_on": 1},
                                            limit=1
                                        )

Comment: Does `query` include `{"active" : False }`?

Comment: Yes it does include it

Comment: Could you try: change from a `boolean` to a `number` for `active`; use an `$inc` on the `active` field `update: { $inc: { active: 1 } }` ; and modify your query to specify that the value of `active` must be equal to `0`? `findAndModify` should be atomic. So, after testing, are you seeing values of `active > 0`?

Comment: Can you include what in your locks is leading you to think that?  FindAndModify is completely atomic. Is it possible you are misinterpreting what you are seeing in the logs?  Also, please include the full findAndModify in the question - including the query.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I included the info into the question. I am pretty sure the reason is the concurrency of find_and_modify calls from several processes. The question is what's the best way to deal with it.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I added the logs - you can see that the same mongo document is read by two different processes, so "active" will be at least 2, if it had an int instead of boolean.

Comment: this is your application log which is showing that each worker got back the same document but not that find_and_modify was called twice(!)  Is each worker calling a function which returns work for them or is each worker calling find_and_modify() directly?  Do you have evidence that find_and_modify was called separately by each worker?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Each worker is a separate process each running the code with find_and_modify.

Comment: Would you please query your queue collection from the shell (if the object in question that two threads printed about is still there, then that record would be good) and include in the post what the full document looks like?  > db.queue.find({id:"5147a90f68e8fe0097002bdf"}).pretty()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26585/discussion-between-vpekar-and-asya-kamsky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a straightforward query to mongodb to get a single job record,

```
job = db.coll.find({query}).limit(1)
```

Next update the record specifying the job id and where `active=false`

```
update_response = db.coll.update(
    {_id:job.id, active=false},
    {$set:{active:true}},
    false,
    false
)
```

If the job has already been updated by another process, the update will not succeed due to the query constraint of `active=false`. Check in the update_response that the record was updated:

```
if update_response['n'] > 0 and update_response['updatedExisting']==true:
    return job
```

If your update didn't succeed then fetch another job and try again.

Comment: If the work completed by each process is very fast, couldn't this result in a lot of contention finding an undone job document? (`find`, then try to `update`, fail, `find`, try ...)

Comment: this seems unnecessary - findAndModify handles this for you. I don't think the OP is interpreting the logs accurately.

Answer (score 4):

Let me make something very clear - it is NOT possible for two different findAndModify commands to return the same document in your scenario.

Not possible.  Here are the first few lines of the method that performs the work:

```
    Lock::DBWrite lk( ns );
    Client::Context cx( ns );

    BSONObj doc;

    bool found = Helpers::findOne( ns.c_str() , queryOriginal , doc );
```

Note line 122 where a WRITE lock is acquired BEFORE the find.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/find_and_modify.cpp#L122

It is *not* possible for two processes to hold the write lock at the same time.  It seems more likely that something different is going on (multiple documents having the same id value, same document being returned by the function that's calling find_and_modify returning it to two threads, something else we don't know enough to speculate about).

FindAndModify is an atomic command which holds an exclusive write lock for the duration of its execution.  My suggestion would be to get to the bottom of what the logs are really showing you rather than making changes to your code based on incorrect/unwarranted assumptions about what must be going on.

Answer (score 1):

Split your "locking" in two stages instead. First update record querying first object that don't have lock timestamp or have expired timestamp and setting new lock. Then just find same object using lock data you've just established.

Comment: I'm not seeing how would this be different from an atomic `findAndModify` that searches for `active:false`.

Comment: I agree with @WiredPrairie - findAndModify just combines the update and return document into one step.