# MongoDB findAndModify from multiple clients

Tags: mongodb

my MongoDB collection is used as a job queue, and there are 3 C++ machines that read from this collection. The problem is that those three can't perform the same job. All jobs need to be made only once.

I fetch all un-done jobs by searching the collection for all records with 'isDone:False' and then update this document, 'isDone:True'. But if 2 machines find the same document at the same time, they would to the same job both. How can I avoid this?

Edit: My question is - do findAndModify really solves that problem?
(After reading [A way to ensure exclusive reads in MongoDb's findAndModify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505176/a-way-to-ensure-exclusive-reads-in-mongodbs-findandmodify))

Comment: I'm confused about your question.  The whole point of `findAnyModify` is that it atomically finds and modifies a document as a single operation, preventing this problem.

Comment: I wonder if it really does after seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505176/a-way-to-ensure-exclusive-reads-in-mongodbs-findandmodify

Comment: @EiTkoCaT http://stackoverflow.com/a/15539348/829571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, findAndModify  solve it.

Ref: [MongoDB findAndModify from multiple clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988230/mongodb-findandmodify-from-multiple-clients)
"...
Note: This command obtains a write lock on the affected database and will block other operations until it has completed; however, typically the write lock is short lived and equivalent to other similar update() operations.
..."

Ref: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update
"...
For unsharded collections, you can override this behavior with the $isolated isolation operator, which isolates the update operation and blocks other write operations during the update. See the isolation operator.
..."

Ref: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/isolated/

Regards,
Moacy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, find-and-modify will solve your problem:

db.collection.findAndModify( {
  query: { isDone: false },
  update: { $set: { isDone: true } },
  new: true,
  upsert: false # never create new docs
} );

This will return a single document that it just updated from false to true.

But you have a serious problem if your C++ clients ever have a hiccup (the box dies, they are killed, the code has an error, etc.) Imagine if your TCP connection drops just after the update on the server, but before the C++ code gets the job. It's generally better to have multi-phase approach:

- change "isDone" to "isInProgress", then when it's done, delete the document. (Now, you can see the stack of "todo" and "being done". If something is "being done" for a long time, the client probably died.
- change "isDone" to "phase" and atomically set it from "new" to "started" (and later set it to "finished"). Now you can see if something is "started" for a long time, the client may have died.

If you're really sophisticated, you can make a partial index. For example, "Only index documents with "phase:{ $ne: 'finished'}". Now you don't need to waste space indexing the millions of finished documents. The index only holds the handful of new/in-progress documents, so it's smaller/faster.